# Height (vertical size) of question summaries now too large on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Sometimes around 22:00 UTC, Tuesday 23 February 2016, the formatting of the SO and MSO sites changed. The height (vertical size) of the question summary boxes (in the "interesting" questions list, for example) is now excessively large.

[image]

Comment: Cross-site post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276065/question-text-mis-aligned

Comment: this has been bugging me too!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a CSS 'float' bug. Adding `float:left;` to the votes box would fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It does look a lot like a CSS float bug as suggested previously. I've seen this most commonly when column widths are percentage based and rounding causes the widths to be greater than 100% of the browser width.

Use display: table-cell or switch to flexbox layout?

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This should be fixed now. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score -5):

I tend to use padding and position absolute for this kind of issue where you have a fixed width on one side and fluid on the other:

```
.item {
    padding-left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80px; /* make sure it's at least the height of .left-element */
}
.item > .left-element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see an `.item` in the CSS stylesheet of Stack Overflow's mobile view.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not suggesting a fix for stack's devs here. I figure they've probably got it in hand. Just a hypothetical approach that I find more robust than floating or displaying inline since both break layout with long, uninterrupted strings.